# Built-in display in MacBook 13 late 2011 non-retina looks weird

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display

About a month ago I bought this MacBook.
Light colours are very light, dark colours are very light. I don't see difference between between some.

In Finder I don't see lines:
[image: Finder without lines]
But under shadows:
[image: Finder with shadows]

I tried to reset NVRAM by holding Option+Command+P+R till boot, trying to calibrate display in expert mode, but it doesn't nothing radically changed.

I'm tired and it driving me crazy :(

Maybe it isn't original display? I need colorimeter like Spyder5?
Or only new laptop with godlike Retina IPS will solve this problem?

Last option is reinstall entire OS. Going to do that on second hard drive.

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: quick check... system prefs > accessibility > display - is display contrast set at Normal? I can repro that 'shadows' look with it set higher

Comment: I think the bug in screenshot two is normal

Comment: Oh, thanks, @Tetsujin 
Many, many thanks! That's was the problem. 
Now, I think, I need to delete all data from previous owner. 
Thanks one more time!

Comment: Glad we found it - I'll set up a proper answer. See this, though for 'deleting all data'. Start from step 5, the previous owner ought to have done 1-4 [though many don't] - https://support.apple.com//HT201065

Comment: I skipped 1-4 on the basis of having backups.  But my former machines remained "authorized" in ITunes.  Steps 1-4 would not prevent that.  Erase and reinstall however, means no user on the new install is logged into anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System Prefs > Accessibility > Display > Display contrast.

If this slider is set to anything other than Normal, this is the effect you will see - though it doesn't show on screenshots, except on the same machine, as it's a 'live' effect only.

[image]